# How can I sort a DNAStringSet object?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have a xstringset object

```
 A DNAStringSet instance of length 151674
          width seq                                                                names               
    [1]     253 GAACAGCATGAATGTTAAAACTGAAATGGATG...TGATGGTTAGGTTTTCAGAAAAAGCAGAAGA LGKD01000001.1 Oc...
    [2]  150158 TATATATATATAGTCAATTCGAGGATGTTAGA...TCCGGATACTATTCCAGAGTTTCCTTGCAAA KQ415657.1 Octopu...
    [3]     619 ATAGACATACACACAAATATTTTTATATCACA...TATATACATATTTATACATATATATATATAT LGKD01000030.1 Oc...
    [4]     359 TCACCAGTGGCAGCCGCGGCTACAGCAAAAGG...CACGGGCTGTACAACGACCCTGATGACTCCG LGKD01000031.1 Oc...
    [5]     239 GAAGTGGTAAAGAGTGCGATGCGCTGAAAAAA...CTCTTTTTTCAGCGCATCGCACTCTTTACCA LGKD01000032.1 Oc...
    ...     ... ...
[151670]    2021 AAAACCTAAACATGTTAAATCAGAGATTGCAA...ATATATAAGTATATATATATATATATATATA KQ434080.1 Octopu...
[151671]     420 CCCCACCTCCACTATCAACACCACTACCACCA...GAAGAAGAAGAAGAAGAAGAAGAAGAAGAAG LGKD01700121.1 Oc...
[151672]     424 ACACACACACACACACACACACATATACATAT...GTAAATGTGTCCGTGTGTAGTAAGCATGTGT LGKD01700122.1 Oc...
[151673]     242 ATATATATATATATATATACATCAACATATAT...ATATGTAGACGTGTGTGTATATATATATATA LGKD01700123.1 Oc...
[151674]     214 CACACACACACACACACACACACACACACACA...ACTCATATGTACAACACACATTTATACGCTT LGKD01700124.1 Oc...
>
```

The I sorted it in decreasing order obtaining this:

```
> sort_oc=sort(width(oc), decreasing = TRUE)

> sort_oc[1:10]
[1] 4064693 3315273 3181678 3174068 2987449 2908116 2784626 2705535 2686354 2631168
```

How can I obtain the correspondant string of each width obtained with the sort?

I expect for example a result like this:

```
          width   seq                                                                names               
     [567] 4064693 GAACAGCATGAATGTTAAAACTGAAATGGATG...TGATGGTTAGGTTTTCAGAAAAAGCAGAAGA  LGKD01000001.1 Oc...           
     [350] 3315273 AAAACCTAAACATGTTAAATCAGAGATTGCAA...ATATATAAGTATATATATATATATATATATA KQ434080.1 Octopu...
```

and so on

Comment: If all strings width are distinct you can try [left_join](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html). Something like,  ```sort_oc %>% left_join(df_DNA, by = "width") ```.

Comment: Are you trying to sort your dataframe by descending order based on your `width` column? If so, does this do what you need? e.g., `oc[order(oc$width, decreasing = T),]`

Comment: Andrew, I think that your suggestion could be the solution, but it didn't work.  `oc[order(oc$width, decreasing =T),]
Error in order(..., decreasing = T) :  argument 1 is not a vector `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Andrew's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10112285/andrew) answer comes very close, but since a `DNAStringSet` is not a data.frame, you need to use the `Biostrings::width` function, not normal subsetting, to get the widths:

```
oc[order(width(oc), decreasing = T),]
```

This will return the same `DNAStringSet` object, ordered by width in descending order

Comment: @jonny if it helped please consider accepting as answer.

Comment: @divibisan if I would to select the strings of width => 1000, is it correct oc[filter(width(oc), => 1000),]

Comment: No, you'd do `oc[width(oc) <= 1000,]`. `width(oc)` makes a numeric vector with the width of each sequence. When you compare it using the greater/less than operator, you get a logical (TRUE/FALSE) vector of whether the condition applies to each sequence which you can use to subset rows. `dplyr::filter` is used *instead* of square bracket subsetting, not along with it. Second, the operators you want are `>=` and `<=`, I'm not sure which one you were going for